# Is there a map-level event to signal the start/end of drawing?

Tags: openlayers-2

In OpenLayers, is there an event which fires when the map starts drawing **any layer**, and another for when the map has finished drawing **all layers**?

I wish to display a "waiting" animation while any layer is still drawing.

The help file for [LoadingPanel](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Addins/LoadingPanel) mentions something which sounds promising, but the sample doesn't work and it mentions tiles (I'd like it to work on vector layers too).

I'm looking for the equivalent of [dojo.connect(map,"onUpdateEnd"...](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/map.htm#onUpdateEnd) in the ArcGIS JS API:

> Fires after layers that are updating their content have completed.
>   This event is often used in combination with onUpdateStart to display
>   a "Map is busy" or "Loading? " message as visual feedback to the
>   end-user.

(As a workaround, I could count the layers in the map, and monitor the status of each layer using `layer.events.register("loadend"...` until they have all finished. Are there other options?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loading panel is available as an add-in and was first mentioned [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/102).
You can either use that or hack it to suit your needs; anyway imho it provides good enough functionality.

The linked example does not work so I took the liberty of assembling a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxpjT/1/

Comment: Thanks for that - much appreciated. I'm finding that both the loading panel and _layer.events.register("loadend"..._ are a bit buggy and don't always register the end of drawing, but I'll explore this in a separate thread if I can't resolve it